# AngularJS {{message}} won't show

Tags: angularjs

Newbie to AngularJS. Trying to display a message from controller onto the html page but it does not show. I'm using AngularJS version 1.6.0 and I binded the controller to the body tag. What am I missing?

/// HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1> 
</body>

</html>
```

// script.js file contents

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.MainController('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello, Angular!";
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the version 1.6 , declaration of global controller is not supported, you need to have a module as well.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[])
app.controller('MainController',function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello, Angular!";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your respoonse Sajeetharan. I edited my code to reflect the change I made but it still not working. Did I miss a step?

Comment: Here is link to my code on Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/rWDDUdupqjT6Tkh1YxBn?p=preview

Comment: @rizzo just change `app.MainController` in `app.controller` code snuppet is working and is right

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to pass the name of your app on the `ng-app` tag.

Like this:

```
<html ng-app="your-app">
```

So Angular understand where it comes.

So, an advice to you is using the `controllerAs` syntax over the classic controller with `$scope` syntax.

Like this:

#### JS file:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp',[])
app.controller('MainController',function($scope) {
    var vm = this; // view model
    vm.message = "Hello, Angular!";
});
```

#### HTML file:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
    <!-- or any other name, your choice -->
    <h1>{{mainCtrl.message}}</h1> 
</body>
```

> Why?: Controllers are constructed, "newed" up, and provide a single
>   new instance, and the controllerAs syntax is closer to that of a
>   JavaScript constructor than the classic $scope syntax.
>
> Why?: It promotes the use of binding to a "dotted" object in the View
>   (e.g. customer.name instead of name), which is more contextual, easier
>   to read, and avoids any reference issues that may occur without
>   "dotting".
>
> Why?: Helps avoid using $parent calls in Views with nested controllers

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#controlleras-view-syntax

I hope this helps you